# How do I calculate reliability between an algorithm and multiple human experts?

Tags: reliability, measurement, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

**Compare inter-rater reliability between 8 human experts and a computer**

I am running a study where I use automated analysis to analyse an EEG signal (brain activity) and quantify certain properties thereof. The computerized method quantifies each property and places it into one of three categories, for example: normal, moderate or abnormal (for some properties, two categories exist).

My goal is to compare the automated method with expert reviewers (i.e., humans), and for this I have sent the same set of recordings to 8 neurologists and asked them to categorize each of the properties for all the recordings.

Now my question: I want to compare the reliability of automated analysis with human reviewing, but because there is no gold-standard, I want to do this by comparing inter-rater variability between expert reviewers using the kappa statistic, and then between the system and reviewers by using the kappa statistic again. How exactly should I do this? My first idea was to calculate the inter-rater agreements between each of reviewers individually (i.e., A vs B, A vs C, etc.) and find the mean thereof, and then do the same for computer analysis by taking the mean of its agreement with each of the reviewers. But this seems wrong to me.

Will this make a fair comparison between human experts and a computer algorithm? I found somewhere on Google that similar measures are needed for comparing algorithms with humans in communication studies such as interpreting texts, and although it seems like they also use kappa values, its not clear to me how fair comparisons are made between the computer and the human.

Comment: Might be something in here of use: http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0020818303573064